# Two members with same name in c#

Tags: c#, json, loops, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Windows Store App (Win Phone 8.1).

I have a to send request to server and it gives response:

**C#:**

```
public class Request
{
    public PWSESSIONRS PWSESSIONRS { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<PWSESSIONR> PWSESSIONRS { get; set; }
}

public class PWSESSIONRS
{
    public PWPROCESSRS PWPROCESSRS { get; set; }
}

public class PWPROCESSRS
{
    public PWERROR PWERROR { get; set; }

    public PWHEADER PWHEADER { get; set; }
    public PWDATA PWDATA { get; set; }
}

public class PWDATA
{
    public GETBIKEDETAIL GETBIKEDETAIL { get; set; }
    public MOBAUTH MOBAUTH { get; set; }

}

public class MOBAUTH
{
    //Request:
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }

    //Response:
    public Row Row { get; set; }

}
```

It shows Error:

> The MOBAUTH already contains a definition for Row

Now, If I do it like this:

```
public class MOBAUTH
{
    //Request:
    [JsonProperty("Row")]
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }

    //Respnse:
    [JsonProperty("Row")]
    public Row Row_ { get; set; }

}
```

It shows runtime Error:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: A member with the name 'Row' already exists on
>   'MyApp.Model.Request.MOBAUTH'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to
>   specify another name.

**JSON REQUEST:**

```
{"PWSESSIONRS":{"PWPROCESSRS":{"PWERROR":null,"PWHEADER":{"DEVICE_LONGITUDE":"77.044510","PROCESS_ID":"","LOGIN_ID":"FiZqnXB4y0u4WNTYG2UXxw==","USER_ID":"FiZqnXB4y0u4WNTYG2UXxw==","IMEI_NO":"64C267E1-545D-4A2B-B726-60F332B18F44","DEVICE_MODEL":"","VERSION_ID":"1.0","PW_SESSION_ID":"3tyEwspAMHj9FvWQzSecuq/7DQMDw0MalYiPIXWaFvg=","DEVICE_LATITUDE":"28.412745","INSTALLATION_ID":"8QO8FLBU1GGEUCIHI44R+A/7DQMDW0MALYIPIXWAFVG=~HCA~614","SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME":"","ORG_ID":"HCA","APP_ID":"HCA","PW_VERSION":"","LOCATION":"","USER_SESSION_ID":"FFv4JAm8bpHauIahnRgs9ZW2ypH7NE41Dz9OZBIXJWnBiR/VRj3yaAmRx+SeZtyc","OS_VERSION":"","SERVER_TIMESTAMP":"","DEVICE_MAKE":"","OUT_PROCESS_ID":"MOBAUTH","SIM_ID":"","PW_CLIENT_VERSION":"3.1","PASSWORD":"FiZqnXB4y0u4WNTYG2UXxw==","DEVICE_TIMESTAMP":"2016-07-23 16:54:09","IS_AUTH":"","LAC":"","MCC":"","MNC":"","CID":"","LAST_TRANSACTION_ID":"","IN_PROCESS_ID":null},"PWDATA":{"GETBIKEDETAIL":null,"MOBAUTH":{"Row":[{"x_VIN":null,"x_phone_no":null,"x_reg_no":null,"x_mobile_no":"9988887777","MessageSource":null,"DetailMessage":null,"DataElements":null,"Message":null,"MsgID":null,"RefID":null,"MessageType":null}]}}}}}
```

**JSON RESPONSE:**

```
{
  "PWSESSIONRS": [
    {
      "PWPROCESSRS": {
        "PWERROR": {
          "MOBAUTH": {
            "Row": {
              "MessageSource": "PLATWARE",
              "DetailMessage": "JSONObject[\"x_reg_no\"] not a string.",
              "DataElements": "",
              "Message": "Please pass valid JSON Data for Process.",
              "MsgID": "plat029",
              "RefID": "MOBAUTH",
              "MessageType": "Error"
            }
          }
        },
        "PWHEADER": {
          "DEVICE_MODEL": "",
          "IMEI_NO": "64C267E1-545D-4A2B-B726-60F332B18F44",
          "VERSION_ID": "1.0",
          "DEVICE_LATITUDE": "28.412745",
          "INSTALLATION_ID": "8QO8FLBU1GGEUCIHI44R+A/7DQMDW0MALYIPIXWAFVG=~HCA~614",
          "APP_ID": "HCA",
          "IS_AUTH": "Y",
          "PW_VERSION": "",
          "OS_VERSION": "",
          "DEVICE_MAKE": "",
          "OUT_PROCESS_ID": "MOBAUTH",
          "SIM_ID": "",
          "PASSWORD": "",
          "DEVICE_LONGITUDE": "77.044510",
          "LOGIN_ID": "FIZQNXB4Y0U4WNTYG2UXXW==",
          "USER_ID": "",
          "PW_SESSION_ID": "3TYEWSPAMHJ9FVWQZSECUQ/7DQMDW0MALYIPIXWAFVG=",
          "SESSION_EXPIRE_TIME": "",
          "ORG_ID": "HCA",
          "LOCATION": "",
          "IN_PROCESS_ID": "MOBAUTH",
          "USER_SESSION_ID": "FFV4JAM8BPHAUIAHNRGS9ZW2YPH7NE41DZ9OZBIXJWNBIR/VRJ3YAAMRX+SEZTYC",
          "SERVER_TIMESTAMP": "2016-07-23 18:46:01",
          "PW_CLIENT_VERSION": "3.1",
          "DEVICE_TIMESTAMP": "2016-07-23 16:54:09"
        },
        "PWDATA": {
          "MOBAUTH": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's still not clear why you've got two properties that you want to call `Row`, or why you want them both to use a JSON property of `Row`. Please clarify your question. (Aside from anything else, it looks like the first property *should* be called `Rows`, given that it's a list...) (I'd also *strongly* advise you to change all your class names to be more readable and follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Its Server which recieves json in and send back response in one format. Just the difference of MOBAUTH in json request and json response

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make it clearer at all.

Comment: I added JSON Request and JSON Response to the question. Kindly check. The data of this json I have to send to server and server gives me data in this json format in response.

Comment: The fact that you've specified the request in a single line really doesn't help - and you should reduce this to a [mcve]. I see you now have an answer, but it's important to learn how to ask a question with all the required information, but nothing extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just create two classes:

```
public class MOBAUTHRequest
{
    //Request:
    [JsonProperty("Row")]
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }    
}

public class MOBAUTHResponse
{
    //Request:
    [JsonProperty("Row")]
    public Row Row { get; set; }
}
```

And use the appropriate one for serialization - `MOBAUTHRequest` with request and `MOBAUTHResponse` with response. But as was stated in the comments, you should definitely consider changing the naming conventions to match C# and use JSON.NET attributes to "rename" for serialization.